# Do math with Decimal values stored in dictionary

Tags: python, list, decimal

I have a python defaultdict(list) with Decimal values for each key. I need to use the Decimals for calculations. I cannot get them from the list data type back into the decimal form.

A sample of my defaultdict.
defaultdict(, {'item1': [Decimal('-232.030449067021')], 'item2': [Decimal('-647.198253946051')], 'item3': [Decimal('-626.390228255337')]})

I need to get these Decimals out of the defaultdict so I can do additional operations to them. For example, I may need to add the Decimal values for item1 and item2. Supposing my defaultdict is named 'd',

```
key1 = 'item1'
key2 = 'item2'
value1 = d.get(key1)
value2 = d.get(key2)
result = value1 + value2
```

gives `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'`

I have tried using `''.join()` to convert to a string so I can use eval(): does not work because of Decimal data type
I have tried using eval() to make python evaluate the list: does not work because the argument must be a string or code object

I am able to successfully do what I want by doing the following:

I have tried mapping to a string

```
key1 = 'item1'
key2 = 'item2'
value1 = Decimal(''.join(map(str,d.get(key1))))
value2 = Decimal(''.join(map(str,d.get(key2))))
result = value1 + value2
```

Is there a simpler way to do this while still preserving the values as Decimals?

Comment: Try `value1 = d.get(key1)[0]`, but why are you putting them into lists in the first place?

Comment: Your values are *lists of single Decimal objects*.

Comment: Why you have `list` as value when you need is a single decimal object entry as the value of `dict`?

Comment: You have your nomenclature backwards. You said, "*with Decimal values for each key*" Your keys are strings. `item1` is a key. `[Decimal('-232.030449067021')]` is a value.

Comment: @Bahrom, they are going into the lists because that was the first way I thought of writing the script.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, I did nor realize I could use Decimal object as the value

Comment: @Robᵩ, I do have my nomenclature correct, the language is just a bit ambiguous. I mean that I have a Decimal value which is associated with each key in the dictionary, not Decimal values **as** the keys

Comment: @Musher - Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in your dictinoary are `list`s, not `Decimal`s. You need to query the list to find the decimal value contained therein:

```
result = value1[0] + value2[0]
```